# Android java get wav file frames

Tags: audio, java

I need to get waveform data from the wav file,but my code returns not right waveform (i compare my results with waveform from fl studio)
This is my code:

```
path = "/storage/emulated/0/FLM User 
Files/My Samples/808 (16).wav";
waveb = FileUtil.readFile(path);
waveb = waveb.substring((int) (waveb.indexOf("data") + 4), (int)(waveb.length()));
byte[] b = waveb.getBytes();

for(int i= 0; i < (int)(b.length/4); i++) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("value", String.valueOf((long)((b[i*4] & 0xFF) + 
            ((b[i*4+1] & 0xFF) << 8))));
        map.put("byte", String.valueOf((long)(b[i*4])));
        l.add(map);
    }
listview1.setAdapter(new 
Listview1Adapter(l));
( (BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My results:
[image: my results]

Fl studio mobile results:
[image: fl studio mobile results]

Comment: I am sorry but you can not simply open a `wav` file, read some bytes and expect to get a wave form. This might work if the AV file is PCM encoded, but a WAV file is a container which can contain quite a few different formats, even for PCM there are multiple variants. Please get yourself a library that reads WAV files properly and decodes the contained data based on the used encoder (or throws an error if the decoder is not supported).

Comment: Thank you, and you know such libraries, I have been looking for ready-made solutions for the second day

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic here on stackoverflow.com. Just use you favorite search engine and search for `JAVA read wav PCM` or check out this pages: https://www.programmersought.com/article/34754764622/ https://android-arsenal.com/tag/8?sort=rating&category=1

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me, I still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can help, given what I know off of the top of my head, but perhaps this will trigger some ideas in your search for a solution.

It looks to me like you are assuming the sound file is 16-bit stereo, little-endian, and that you are only attempting to inspect one track of the stereo frame. Can you confirm this?

There's at least one way this plan could go awry: the .wav header may be an odd number of bytes in length, and you might not be properly parsing frame boundaries as a result. As an experiment, maybe try adding a different increment when you reference the b[] array? For example b[i*4 + 1] and b[i*4 + 2] instead of b[i*4] and b[i*4 + 1]. This won't solve the general problem of parsing .wav headers, but it could at least get you closer to understanding the situation.

It sure looks like Java's `AudioInputStream` is not accessible in Android, and all searches that I have that ask if there is an Android equivalent are turning up unanswered.

I've used [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) for the playback of raw PCM, but I don't know an Android equivalent for reading wav files. The [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) class and read() methods look interesting as the read methods store PCM data in a short array, but I've never used them, and they seem to be hard-coded to the microphone for input.

There used to be a Google Group: andraudio@googlegroups.com. IDK if it is still around. I used to go there and occasionally ask about things.

Maybe there is code you can use from [Oboe](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media) or [libGDX](https://libgdx.com/)? The latter makes use of OpenAL and is for cross-platform development, with Android as one of the target platforms. I have not looked into either for this question.

If you do find the answer, it would be great to post it as a solution. This seems to be a matter that many have tried to solve and given up on.